# open website code in java as illusion of web browser

Tags: java, networking

I want to open a website in web browser. I know it is easy but i want to do it in different way ... 
It is like proxy server .I have made a java code that will get content(source code) of webpage and when browser request localhost on particular port number this code writes source code in browser. But instead of getting web page I am getting source code of webpage in browser and also i want to make a request from java code as a illusion of browser means server should feel that that request is made from a browser and not from java console.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    URL ul = null;
    HttpURLConnection ulc = null;

    ServerSocket server = null;
    Socket client = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    String c = null;

        server = new ServerSocket(9898);
        System.out.println("Server is waiting for clients on port no 9898....");
        while(client == null){
        client = server.accept();
        }
        System.out.println("Connected.....");
        out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        ul = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        ulc = (HttpURLConnection)ul.openConnection();
        in = new DataInputStream(ulc.getInputStream());

        while((c = in.readLine())!=null){
            out.writeBytes(c);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        client.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: try sending the data to a text file, and then use the text file as a source, and play around with it, particularly the header. also make sure to try looking at the webpage source in chrome and firefox.

Comment: that is working and i have done it earlier but i wanted direct communication between browser and my localhost server ... bt it's behavior is unpredictable. sometimes it is working and sometimes not.so i need a way to handle those resources which is provided by google.com(in this example).simple text responce i m saving in string and writing on client(browser).but it is not working all the time

Comment: do you need to use google.com? maybe you could use a less complex page?

Answer (score 0):

Loading web pages is not quite as simple as you probably think. Both the browser and the server use a protocol called [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). In simple terms, the browser sends a request consisting of a request line, headers and sometimes data, and the server responds with a response line, headers and data. Most web pages also have related resources that need to be loaded for displaying the page (such as images, stylesheets and scripts), and each resource is loaded through a separate request.

Your program only accepts one request, completely ignores the details of the request, and then loads a fixed web page and sends it as the response. The way you are loading the web page (with a `URL`), you are only getting the data part of the response (the page source); the response line and the headers are missing. The headers are very important as one of them (named "Content-Type") specifies what kind of resource it is - web page, image or something else. Without it, browsers usually assume the data is plain text and display it accordingly.

So if you want your experiment to work better, you need to make sure you send a complete and valid HTTP response to the browser. You can probably reconstruct the response line and headers from the `HttpURLConnection` object. Or you can use sockets directly to load the web page.

A better solution would be to use a java web server (such as Jetty) in which you'd run a servlet that loads the remote page using an HTTP client library (such as Apache HttpComponents) and does the necessary processing of addresses and headers. But.. small steps :)

Comment: ok .. that is done .. i set user_agent,charset and content-type now it is giving me unstyled page ... but how can i now get all those files and resources using headers ?? can you give me any link ???

Comment: sorry dude .. i m confused .. i added necessary headers but still the behavior of my program is unpredictable ... i mean sometime it is showing webpage and sometime just plain text(source code)...